# Move shop to a other and new domain

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i’m stuck.
I want to move a magento shop to a new domein.
Example: From testdomain.com/shop to newdomain.com/shop

I worked like this so the old shop on newdomain.com was able to keep running while building a new store on a testplace.

How can i move the shop to the newdomain.com ??

I made a sql backup from the testshop; this is a file of 15MB.
In the file there are references to testdomain.com. Offcource; i need to replace them by newdomain.com.

This replacing takes along time and mostly end ups in crashing file.
Is there another way to move a shop to a new domain ??

Thanks,
Dave

http://p1.b7d.com/magento/meghzal/

Answer (score 1):

dont play with your sql file just import it as it is. if you only have 1 store view you only have to change 2 values to make you shop running.

1. Copy all file to you new webserver
2. Make the media and the var folder writeable by the webserver
3. Edit 'app/etc/local.xml' normally you only have to edit the database connection
4. With you favorite mysql tool edit the values under these paths: `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` set them to your new domain like `http://newdomain.com/`. if you have an ssl certificate use https for the secured one if not use normal http.
5. Now very important clear the cache. normally the cache is under `var/cache` but in case this one is not writable magento switches to the tmp folder of you server. So check you tmp folder for something like `/tmp/magento` and remove it

Comment: For #4, you might want to mention that the table is `core_config_data` and the values you've provided is actually the `path` value to search for.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to COPY installation of Magento to another server use the manual by Fantus here. Beware of different php.ini configuration, and OS (from Win to Unix set correct the rights by chmod)

If you have the same installation and ONLY CHANGING ENTRANCE DOMAIN to the same installation of Magento:

1. configure your domain A record to IP adress of your server
2. configure a vitual host of your ewb server (apache or etc) to reverse domain to magento folder
3. change configuration of new domain in magento/app/local.xml

Clear the magento/var/ folder (not neesesary)